# Adding assets to Android Project, Visual Studio 2015 CTP

Tags: android, assets, visual-studio-2015

I am attempting to add assets to an android project, using Visual Studio 2015 CTP. When I add files to ProjectName.Packaging/res the build fails with the error:

```
1>  -package-resources:
1>       [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
1>       [aapt] Creating full resource package...
1>       [aapt] invalid resource directory name: C:\ProjectName\ARM\Release\Package\res image.png
1>  
1>  BUILD FAILED
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:932: The following error occurred while executing this line:
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:950: null returned: 1
1>  
1>  Total time: 0 seconds
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\AndroidPackaging\Android.Common.targets(280,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3\\bin\ant.bat" debug -Dout.final.file="C:\ProjectName\ARM\Release\ProjectName.Packaging.apk"" exited with code 1.
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was able to answer my question. Right click ProjectName.Packages -> Add -> New Folder and name it assets. Right click assets -> Add -> Existing Item -> select the asset you wish to add.

If the error persists, clean project AND manually delete the build folder from C:\ProjectName\ARM\Release or whatever. Rebuild.

Comment: In newer versions of the Visual Studio Android templates (I'm using 2015 Preview 5 but I think this also applies to 2015 Update 3) the folder structure has changed.  The assets directory needs to be in app/src/main/assets.

Answer (score 0):

The file name of your resources can't contain spaces, use a _ instead

Comment: The filename does not contain a space. The actual path is C:\ProjectName\ARM\Release\Package\res\image.png That the error puts a space instead of a slash may be a hint.

Comment: Then I believe the problem is that the resources folder is pointing to the image.png instead of the res directory